# Eclipse C++ project not building: Constructor Destructor Issue

Tags: c++, constructor, eclipse-cdt, vtable

I have all the class definitions in a header file: ModelModule.h. I have provided the sample code for that file below where I have given the declaration of 2 classes and its member functions:

```
#pragma once

#if !defined( MODELMODULE_H )
#define MODELMODULE_H


//Required header files

class CModelModule;
class COrdProbitMM;

class CModelModule
// virtual base class for all types of modeling modules
{
    friend class CSimCoordinator;
    friend class CHouseholdCoordinator;
    friend class CGenericHousehold;

    public:
        CModelModule(void);
        ~CModelModule(void);

    protected:
        std::string         m_Label;        
        std::vector<int>        m_AvailEndAttr;     
        void GetVarValues(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<double> &);


    public:


        virtual void    Configure(void){};
        virtual void loadXmlString(xmlNodePtr pXmlNode, xmlDocPtr pXmlDoc, xmlChar * con);
        virtual void    SaveXml(std::ofstream& fout){};

        double mrand(void); 
        double UniformRand ();          // returns a U[0,1] random number 
        double StdNormalRand ();        // returns a N(0,1) random number
};

class COrdProbitMM : public CModelModule
// Class represent the ordered-probit models
{
    friend class CSimCoordinator;
    friend class CHouseholdCoordinator;
    friend class CMMRunner;

    public:
        COrdProbitMM(CSimCoordinator& simcord, std::string& sLabel);
        COrdProbitMM(CSimCoordinator& simcord, std::string& sLabel, int nAlts);
        ~COrdProbitMM(void);

    private: 

        int             m_Max_nAlts;    
        std::vector<double>     m_Thresholds;   

    public:
        void    Configure(void);
        void    copyConfigure(COrdProbitMM* that);

        int  Run(CHouseholdObject*);
        int  Run(CPersonObject*);


        void loadXmlString(xmlNodePtr pConfNode,  xmlDocPtr pXmlDoc, xmlChar* con);

    private:
        int     Run(void);
};
```

Now the function definitions has been given in a .cpp file: ModelModule.cpp. Note: The header file has been included

```
#include "ModelModule.h"
//Other header files

//Code for all the other functions defined here

//Given below are the code for how the constructors and destructors are defined

COrdProbitMM::~COrdProbitMM(void)
{
}

CModelModule::CModelModule(void)
{
}

CModelModule::~CModelModule(void)
{   
}
```

I have rid the code of any syntactic error. However when I build the code I get the error make: ***[ProjectName] Error1. On inspecting the console I find the following being displayed:

```
Building target: Project Name
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "XYZ"  ./src/XYZ.o ./src/DataCache\ -\ Copy.o ./src/DataCache.o ./src/DataCoordinator.o ./src/DataObject.o ./src/HouseholdCoordinator.o ./src/
LinearEquation.o ./src/MMRunner.o ./src/MainFrm.o ./src/ModelModule.o ./src/SimCoordinator.o ./src/main.o   -lxml2 -lsqlite3

./src/ModelModule.o: In function `CModelModule::CModelModule()':
ModelModule.cpp:(.text._ZN12CModelModuleC2Ev[CModelModule::CModelModule()]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for CModelModule'
./src/ModelModule.o: In function `CModelModule::~CModelModule()':
ModelModule.cpp:(.text._ZN12CModelModuleD2Ev[CModelModule::~CModelModule()]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for CModelModule'

./src/ModelModule.o:(.rodata._ZTI12COrdProbitMM[typeinfo for COrdProbitMM]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CModelModule'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Project Name] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I checked out this forum for the vtable error and it was mentioned that the problem is when we declare a constructor/destructor but never define it. But that does not seem to be a problem in this case as it was explicitly done in ModelModule.cpp. There seems to be something very basic that is going on here that is slipping my attention.

- What is it that I'm missing?
- Can you tell me what is with the virtual function and how it caused the error to come?
- Does it somehow link up with the constructor and destructor?

Comment: Have you provided definitions for **All** the methods which you declared as `virtual`? The error is typical where you miss providing defintion for a `virtual` method.Standard mandates all the methods except pure `virtual` should have a definition.

Comment: virtual void    Configure(void){};
    virtual void loadXmlString(xmlNodePtr pXmlNode, xmlDocPtr pXmlDoc, xmlChar * con);
    virtual void    SaveXml(std::ofstream& fout){}; - I have defined these three....

Comment: How about `CModelModule::loadXmlString`?

Comment: You need to add empty function definition for `loadXmlString` as you have done for `SaveXml` (`virtual void loadXmlString(xmlNodePtr pXmlNode, xmlDocPtr pXmlDoc, xmlChar * con){}`) or make it a pure virtual function (`virtual void loadXmlString(xmlNodePtr pXmlNode, xmlDocPtr pXmlDoc, xmlChar * con) = 0;`). Also semi-colon after function definition of `SaveXml` & `Configure` are redundant

Comment: @another.anon.coward - That was it!! I had not defined the virtual version of the loadXmlString().... The code got built!! Thanks a lot to all you guys!!

For knowledge and self education: Can you tell me what is with the virtual function and how it caused the error to come? Does it somehow link up with the constructor and destructor?

Comment: @RazorXsr: I added an explanation about the problem.Hth.

Comment: You also need to make `~CModelModule` `virtual`, since inheritance of polymorphic class requires it's destructor to be virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root Cause:**
You get the error because the C++ Standard mandates that **All** virtual methods of a class except the pure virtual methods **Must** have a definition<sup>[#1]</sup>.

**Solution:**
Either provide definitions to all your `virtual` methods or make them pure `virtual`.

**Explanation:**
The error generated by gcc in such scenarios is at best mis-leading. Here is a [**sample program**](http://www.ideone.com/q1OZO) which demonstrates the problem you have:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    virtual void doSomething() { }
    virtual void doSomethingMore();
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.doSomething();
    obj.doSomethingMore();
    return 0;
}
```

compilation info:

> /home/4VqWl0/ccMjLi2V.o: In function `main':
>
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to`vtable for MyClass`.
>
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to`MyClass::doSomethingMore()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

As you see GCC is notorious in reporting errors for this particular type of problem.

**Does it somehow link up with the constructor and destructor?**

The **[gcc faq](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables)** doccuments it as well:

> The ISO C++ Standard specifies that all virtual methods of a class that are not pure-virtual must be defined, but does not require any diagnostic for violations of this rule `[class.virtual]/8`. Based on this assumption, GCC will only emit the implicitly defined constructors, the assignment operator, the destructor and the virtual table of a class in the translation unit that defines its first such non-inline method.
>
> **Therefore, if you fail to define this particular method, the linker may complain about the lack of definitions for apparently unrelated symbols**. Unfortunately, in order to improve this error message, it might be necessary to change the linker, and this can't always be done.
>
> The solution is to ensure that all virtual methods that are not pure are defined. Note that a destructor must be defined even if it is declared pure-virtual `[class.dtor]/7`.

Good Read:

**[What does it mean that the "virtual table" is an unresolved external?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.10)**

---

<sup>[#1]</sup>**C++03 Standard: 10.3 Virtual functions   [class.virtual]**

> A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is required (3.2).

Comment: That made the problem crystal and put it in proper perspective!! Thank you!