# Linker errors creating QLabel with doubleclick event

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qlabel

I'm creating a QLabel subclass which adds the DoubleClickEvent to it.  I have created the following, but I'm getting some strange linker errors, maybe someone can point out what I've done wrong?

```
//Header
#ifndef IMAGE_LABEL_H
#define IMAGE_LABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class image_label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
image_label(QWidget* parent = 0);
~image_label();

signals:
    void doubleClicked();

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * e);

};


#endif


//CPP 

#include "image_label.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>

image_label::image_label(QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
}

image_label::~image_label()
{
}

void image_label::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        emit doubleClicked();
        QLabel::mouseDoubleClickEvent(e);
    }
}
```

I get the following linker errors when I compile:

```
 image_label.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall image_label::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@image_label@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

  image_label.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall image_label::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@image_label@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)

  image_label.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall image_label::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@image_label@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

  image_label.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall image_label::doubleClicked(void)" (?doubleClicked@image_label@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall image_label::mouseDoubleClickEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseDoubleClickEvent@image_label@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
```

Can anybody help why I get these errors?

Comment: Not in to QT but have seen such linking errors [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006711/eclipse-c-project-not-building-constructor-destructor-issue/10007510#10007510).Any virtual functions which you don't define. Most likely, not but just worth checking I think.

Answer (score 1):

You must run the MOC preprocessor on the file `image_label.h`. This generates a file `moc_image_label.cpp`that you must include in the build. The error message indicates that you have not done this. (The symbols `image_label::metaObject` etc. that are mentioned in the error message are defined in `moc_image_label.cpp`.)